# Can a back row player joust at the net without jumping?

Tags: rules, volleyball

A tall back-row player executes a legal back-row attack, ending up near the net, and is immediately in a position to "joust" for a tight ball by simply reaching above the net, without jumping, winning the point.  Is this an illegal block by a back-row player?

The ruleset in use by this league is unclear, bonus points for any differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an illegal block. Quoting [FIVB rule 14.1.1](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf):

> Blocking is the action of players close to the net to intercept the ball
>   coming from the opponent by reaching higher than the top of the net,
>   regardless of the height of the ball contact. Only front-row players are
>   permitted to complete a block, but at the moment of the contact with
>   the ball, a part of the body must be higher than the top of the net.

and 14.6.2 which lists the faults which can be made while blocking:

> A back-row player or a Libero completes a block or participates in a
>   completed block.

In particular, note that it is the fact of reaching higher than the top of the net which makes it a block. Whether or not the player jumps is irrelevant.